# how to answer question for Snowflake interview position data engineer SQL optimization query anyone could solve?

Tags: sql, optimization

In the absence of a cost-based or statistics-based optimization do you think the following query will be performant? Explain your answer.

```
SELECT * from SMALL_DIMENSION_TABLE small JOIN BIG_FACT_TABLE big ON small.x = big.x;
```

How to answer this question. How to transfrom this query into perfomant?

Comment: This seems a rather strange question given the fact that essentially all relational databases out there use cost based optimizers. I am not aware of any modern dbms that wouldn't have that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Ironically, I was just investigating this with regards to BigQuery.  Google says both that they order the joins from biggest to smallest AND that they recommend writing queries with the biggest tables first.  I guess they don't trust their optimizer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: wow, that's disappointing. But good to know, thanks

Comment: I understand that is strange but this is test questiion for open position of Techincal support engineer  and no one can help?

Comment: @Anatolee . . . You should answer the question based on your knowledge of the Snowflake optimizer.  If you are not familiar with that, then the position doesn't seem appropriate for you.

Comment: what it about the absence of a cost-based or statistics-based optimization! I know a lot of profile optimizer cachine and clustering and concurrency